# Neo4j Merging two nodes within the same dataset

Tags: json, graph, neo4j, merge, relationship

Hello I am a beginner to neo4j and graph databases in general. I have watched tutorials but I am struggling with a merge statement when trying to apply my learning to my own project.

Do give some context I am importing my data using apoc.load.json and the format of my json file is:

```
{"train_id":3326, "relevant":1, "date":"2020-01-22", "user_id":134680773, "tweet":"blah blah text", "conversation_id":"1220212769825", "id":"122021276"}
```

I am able to load my data fine into neo4j
But I am having trouble with my actual query to create the connections within my data.
What I want to do is create nodes for every row called "Tweets" and a node for every row called "date", Tweets should store all the info in the json , and date should store just the "date" info from it. 
I then want to create a connection between the nodes to display different node for days and connect them with all the different tweets that were created on that day.

Here is the query I have created thus far:

```
//Creating Nodes and Labels
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///file.json") 
Yield value
With value LIMIT 1000
Merge (a:Tweet{id:value.id,date:value.date,train_id:value.train_id})
Merge (d:Date{date:value.date})
Merge (a)-[:SAME_DATE]->(d)
```

Unfortunately what I get with this is 1 date node which happens to be the first date in the file, and a bunch of tweets connected to it. Rather than all the various dates and the tweets that correspond to those specific dates.
Here is an image for what it currently looks like, any help with the query would be much appreciated as I am a beginner with this and I have looked at various examples and haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks! as a side note how would you change the orange bubbles to show like the train_id rather than the date in the graph.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that all the tweets don’t have the same date ?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the data, the first few hundred do but there is about 5000 entries.

Comment: Sure, you have distinct values in first thousands rows?

Comment: Try to print distinct dates in first thousand rows without creates nodes and see if you have distinct values

Comment: What is the result of this following query : `CALL apoc.load.json("file:///file.json") 
Yield value
With value LIMIT 1000 RETURN count(distinct value.date)` ?

Comment: 230 is what it returns

Comment: What query did you use to generate that visualization? Also, what does `MATCH (d:Date) RETURN COUNT(d)` return?